# How can I resolve this Talend API error: IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute?

Tags: api, talend

I'm using the tRESTClient object in Talend Open Studio for ESB - Version: 8.0.1.

This REST is doing a POST (I'm trying to write data into an API). The link I'm using is an https link that I've tested using Postman. There is also a header api-key, in Talend, I have that x-api-key setup as a query parameter.

When I run the job, I get the error:   *IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute*

I tried adding a tSetProxy object, but it didn't fix the error (I used the https defaults on the set proxy object). How can I resolve this error?

Comment: usually this kind of error means that the endpoint you defined in tRESTClient contains unresolved variables. Are you sure about your endpoint ? Could you add a screenshot ?

Comment: Ultimately, this job is supposed to loop thru a series of API URLs. So, I used contexts to create the link for each pass thru the loop (the very end of the https is an application code that is different for each iteration). I tried copy/pasting the actual link into the tRestClient object and I got a different error:
ConnectException invoking <https link>: Connection timed out: no further information